# Trouble outputting table with MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with the following columns:

```
bookingdatetime (datetime)
promo
pickuploc
quotedprice
```

I want to query the table so I can see how much in dollars were spent using each specific promo code in only a specific city. I want the output to look like this:

```
Month/Year      Promo     Amount Sent
01/20           test1     100
02/20           test1     50
02/20           test2     50
02/20           test3     50
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feccb3/1

As you can see, my query is not giving me the correct output. I need it to count each promo used in each month. So I can get an accurate idea of what is generating me the most profit.

Here is my query for reference:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y') AS mont_year,
promo as Promo,
SUM(quotedprice) AS Amount_Sent
FROM `reservations`
WHERE pickuploc = 'la' AND promo <> '' GROUP BY promo
```

Not great at MySQL, had lots of help on this and still not working. Please advise.

Comment: You should not have a distinct with a group by (group by is distinct)

Answer (score 1):

The year-month is missing from the `GROUP BY` clause, and also you don't need to use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%Y-%m') AS year_month,
    promo AS Promo,
    SUM(quotedprice) AS Amount_Sent
FROM reservations
WHERE pickuploc = 'la' AND promo <> ''
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%Y-%m'),
    promo
ORDER BY
    DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%Y-%m'),
    promo;
```

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year_month' at line 2" try running it in the fiddle

Comment: @Bob I had s stray typo, sorry.